# Does PCIe x1 mean a standard height and full length?

Tags: pci-express

I need a new computer that have a PCIe x1 slot that takes an standard height, full length PCIe card.

In this specification (taken from HP Z230 Tower Workstation, http://www8.hp.com/us/en/campaigns/workstations/z230.html)

> Exapansion slots
>   1 PCIe Gen3 x16
>   1 PCIe Gen2 x4 slot/x16 connector
>   1 PCIe Gen2 x1 slot/x4 connector
>   1 PCIe Gen2 x1 slot, 1 PCI 32-bit

does this mean that the slots can take a standard height, full length PCIe card
or must it be explicitly mentioned?

Comment: Assume nothing about physical dimensions from an interface list.

Comment: The fact that you have x16, and you have the option of full size, and at least one slot video cards should indicate they are full size I think

Answer (score 2):

The size of the cards typically depends on the size of the case of the PC. On most tower PC's the expansion slots will allow for standard height, full length PCI cards. If you go with the small form factor (SFF) you'll need to look at half-height cards and go with something that's a more standard length. Most high-end graphics cards aren't going to fit in a SFF.
The x1, x4, x16  are specifically the number of "lanes" attributed to each card which is physically the number of copper pins that are inserted into your motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, RTFM. For a DIY system, consult both the motherboard manual, and the case manual. For this, [consult the service manual](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c04181341-1%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken). Try page 60 for a list of what slots are available and what would fit

Failing this, considering these workstations have space for standard, single wide (at least) video card. Unless they did something odd, there should DEFINITELY be space for your x1 card somewhere.